# How to find the intersection of two lines on a plane in 3D space.

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d

> My Question is: How do I math the intersection($P5$) of $\overline{P3,P0}$ and $\overline{P7,P8}$ ?

I'm trying to find the intersection of two lines in a 3d space, (XYZ) on a plane.
I have a plane, it is formed by 3 points

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
P1\\\hline
1\\
1\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
P0\\\hline
-1\\
.345\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
P3\\\hline
1\\
.275\\
-1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I also have 2 other points on that plane

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
P7\\\hline
.420\\
.687\\
.661\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
P8\\\hline
.295\\
.555\\
.410\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now if I draw a line though $\overline{P7,P8}$, it should be intersecting the line $\overline{P0,P3}$, at

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
P5\\\hline
.060\\
.308\\
-.060\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

(consequently, it should also intersect line $\overline{P1,P0}$ somewhere (.589,.866,1) )

My Question is: How do I math the intersection($P5$) of $\overline{P3,P0}$ and $\overline{P7,P8}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector for a general point on the line $P_7P_8$ is
$$\lambda(P_7-P_8)+P_8=\lambda\begin{pmatrix}0.125\\0.132\\0.251\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0.295\\0.555\\0.410\end{pmatrix},$$
where $\lambda$ is any real number. You can think of this formula as starting at the point $P_8$, then shifting your position by a scalar multiple of the vector $\overrightarrow{P_8P_7}$.

Likewise the equation for a general point on line $P_0P_3$  is
$$\mu(P_3-P_0)+P_0=\mu\begin{pmatrix}2\\-0.07\\-2\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}1\\0.275\\-1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Equating these two expressions should give you three equations (one for each component) for $\lambda$ and $\mu$, which you can then solve.

Comment: And those three equations would then be these?  
[$X: .295 + \lambda*.125 = 1 + \mu*2$] ~~~~~~  
[$Y: .555 + \lambda*.132 = .275 + \mu*-.07$] ~~~~
[$Z: .410 + \lambda*.251 = -1 + \mu*-2$]

Comment: Yep! After you solve for $\lambda,\mu$, remember to plug in one of the values back to the equation to get the actual position vector.

Comment: But there isn't a solution for those?

Comment: Well your actual numbers are rounded, so there's a tiny bit of error. Just solve the first two equations. If you plug those values into the third equation, the LHS and RHS differ by about 0.001, which is acceptable given your rounding.

Comment: okay got it, thanks for the help!

Comment: μ(P3−P0)+P0 should be μ(P3−P0)+P3 in your answer?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference -- both expressions describe the line $P_0P_3$. The expression I wrote has $\mu=0$ for the point $P_0$, the expression you wrote has $\mu=0$ for the point $P_3$. So we're just parametrising the line in slightly different ways.